# Rails log in form case-sensitivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, case-sensitive

How would I make a log in form case-insensitive? An example would be a user who signs up with the username "Ralph" can log in after registering using either "Ralph" or "ralph", but store the username as "Ralph" for use with things like friendly_id and views?

It'd be nice if there was a way to do this that wasn't database specific, but implemented in ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Store the username however they give it to you, but call `downcase` on the string before passing it into whatever method you are authenticating with.

Comment: How will that do anything useful? If it already has to match case, what will downcasing the username before trying to authenticate do?